# Ever thought of adding a Poll-of-the-Day option to SE?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I was wondering if the SE team had considered adding a Poll option to their framework.

A lot of the questions here are similiar to a poll and it would be nice to total results and view summaries. Personally, I love viewing statistics and seeing how my opinion compares to what other popular opinions are.

A site I visit a lot, [www.gamefaqs.com](http://www.gamefaqs.com), always has a poll of the day up and whenever I go to their site I always take a minute to check it out. It's on the main page in the right sidebar. Polls are based on user submissions and you can view a history of past polls and their results.

Comment: Could you explain the -1? I'd post this elsewhere if someone told me where

Comment: The unofficial policy on meta discussion sites has been that a down vote means "I don't like this idea" not that the question is in the wrong place. (See: [Why are people downvoting my question on Meta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42558/why-are-people-downvoting-my-question-on-meta))

Comment: @Mark: Ok, thanks. I don't normally post on meta and only did since it really isn't something related to programmers

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I actually think this is a great idea, for the following reasons:

1. They're useless, apart from idle entertainment. Limiting them to 1/day limits the amount of useless fluff posted on the site.
2. People post them anyway. They were discouraged on SO, and they're now "discouraged" here... But, people post them anyway. A quick search hints at the presence of >400 such questions... and the site's only been up for a bit over 3 months! See also #1...
3. They *are* fun. Nothing like seeing a totally-bogus indicator that you're in the moral majority to boost your ego... Except maybe seeing a totally-bogus indicator that the majority of other users really *are* the idiots you think they are.

Comment: Yeah I agree, it would be fun and lower the amount of poll-like questions (what hours do you work, how many projects are you working on, whats your favorite|primary language, etc), but I do see their reasoning since they do not want SE to become a forum filled with opinions instead of answers. I think it would enhance SE instead of hurt it, but thats just my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Poll of the day type polls are almost entirely meaningless as statistics, unless you're interested in comparing your opinions to those of a non-representative, self selected group which can't be generalised in any way to meaningfully represent a wider audience.

Besides, surely if a question is interesting enough it should just be a straight question, if it's not then no need to ask it?

Comment: I am thinking it would provide an alternative to asking questions such as "What's your favorite [Editor|Language|OperatingSystem|etc]". Instead of posting a question about that which would likely be closed, they could propose it as a Poll

Comment: @Rachel those questions *have no place here* in any form. Giving them legitimacy by adding them as polls sends the wrong message.

Comment: @Rachel - But do we really care about that sort of thing?  The answer is never going to be useful for the reasons I outline.  Questions are either useful (in which case great) or not (in which case we surely don't want them in any form)?

Comment: I see your point. I find them interesting, however they are not questions with real answers, which is SE's ultimate goal.